# How Do I Use PowerShell to Get a SQL Server Backup Status?

Tags: sql-server, backup, powershell

I need a power-shell script to obtain the following information Name of the database , LastBackupDate of the database and this information should be sent via an email converting the results to HTML format :) if we do have chance of getting the script done which will be .ps1 file I need to know how to run as a sql job.

Comment: @@Pathum Anjana why back history information using Power-shell and not from MSDB tables ? as you want to schedule a job for html output?

Comment: As long as I can get the following information and serve my purpose I'm fine with it :) let me know your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code gets backup history for all databases on a server and generates HTML report

**Step 1:**

```
   DECLARE @Body VARCHAR(MAX),
        @TableHead VARCHAR(MAX),
        @TableTail VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET NoCount ON ;


    SET @TableTail = '</body></html>' ;

    SET @TableHead = '<html><head>' + '<style>'
        + 'td {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:10pt;} '
        + '</style>' + '</head>' + '<body>'


    SELECT  @Body = ''



    SELECT  @Body = @Body + '<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>'
            + '<tr><td bgcolor=#E6E6FA>Database Name </td>'
            + '<td width="100px" bgcolor=#E6E6FA>Backup Size</td>'
            + '<td width="100px" bgcolor=#E6E6FA>Time Taken</td>'
            + '<td width="100px" bgcolor=#E6E6FA>Backup Start Date</td>'
            + '<td width="100px" bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>First LSN</b></td>'
            + '<td width="100px" bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Last LSN</b></td>'
            + '<td width="100px" bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Backup Type</b></td>'
            + '<td width="100px" bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Server Name</b></td>'
            + '<td width="100px" bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Recovery Model</b></td>'
            + '<td width="300px" bgcolor=#E6E6FA>Physical Device Name</td>   </tr>'


    -- Backup History script of AAsim Adbullah                
    -- http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/11/10/sql-server-get-database-backup-history-for-a-single-database/ 
    SELECT  @Body = @Body
            + ( SELECT  td = s.database_name, '',
                        td = CAST(CAST(s.backup_size / 1000000 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(14))+ ' ' + 'MB', '',
                        td = CAST(DATEDIFF(second, s.backup_start_date,
                                           s.backup_finish_date) AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' ' + 'Seconds', '',
                        td = s.backup_start_date,  '',
                        td = CAST(s.first_lsn AS VARCHAR(50)), '',
                        td = CAST(s.last_lsn AS VARCHAR(50)), '',
                        td = CASE s.[type]
                               WHEN 'D' THEN 'Full'
                               WHEN 'I' THEN 'Differential'
                               WHEN 'L' THEN 'Transaction Log'
                             END,'',
                        td = s.server_name, '',
                        td = s.recovery_model,'',
                        td = m.physical_device_name,''
                FROM    msdb.dbo.backupset s
                        INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily m ON s.media_set_id = m.media_set_id
                WHERE   s.backup_start_date >= DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,GETDATE() - 1)) -- --- Date check for one day backup history information
                ORDER BY backup_start_date DESC,
                        backup_finish_date
              FOR
                XML PATH('tr')
              ) + '</table>'



    SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body, '_x0020_', SPACE(1))
    SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body, '_x003D_', '=')
    SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body, '<tr><TRRow>1</TRRow>', '<tr bgcolor=#C6CFFF>')
    SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body, '<TRRow>0</TRRow>', '')


    SELECT  @Body = @TableHead + @Body + @TableTail


    IF ( @Body IS NULL ) 
        BEGIN 
                EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='sqlcache@blogspot.com',  -- Add Valid Email Id
                @subject = 'Backup History Information',
                @profile_name = 'AA.SC', -- Change Profile Name
                @body = 'No Backup History Found for past 1 Day',
                @body_format = 'HTML' ;

        END
    ELSE 
    Begin
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='sqlcache@blogspot.com', -- Add Valid Email Id
                @subject = 'Backup History Information',
                @profile_name = 'AA.SC', -- Change Profile Name
                @body = @Body,
                @body_format = 'HTML' ;
    END
```

**Step 2:**
create a new job add this code in step and schedule it according to your requirement
[image]

Comment: Wow, you've hard-coded your table to be over 5,000px wide. How many monitors does that span?

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand you mentioned my mistake, I updated script. but width="100px" is optional property of TD tag.