# The database mail configuration saved into a temp table

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2016, dynamic-sql, database-mail

I am currently dealing with a bunch of servers and they have different Database Mail Configurations.

I can see [the Database Mail configuration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47058/how-can-i-see-the-current-database-mail-configuration) for each of those servers.

I use the following script:

```
--==========================================================
-- getting the Database Mail Configuration
-- Marcelo Miorelli
-- 1-April-2014
--==========================================================

select @@servername
--SQLSALON1\STOCKALLOCATION



-- http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47058/how-can-i-see-the-current-database-mail-configuration

EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_configure_sp;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_account_sp;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_profile_sp;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_profileaccount_sp;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_principalprofile_sp;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_account_sp
```

Actually the procedure `msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_account_sp` is my favourite in this regard.

Now I would like to email the backup history for the day before (only full and differential backups) and I need to find out the profile name for each of those servers.

I would like to get this done by saving the contents of the above procedure into a temp table or table variable and just query the info from it by the time that I have all the data I need and I am about to email them.

How can I do that for those procedures, specially the sysmail_help_account_sp?

I specifically need to find out the `profile name`.
I have used `DBA` for the script below.

this is the script I am using [to generate the contents of my email](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81432/how-do-i-use-powershell-to-get-a-sql-server-backup-status):

```
--=====================================================================================================================
-- sql server backups report in HTML format to be emailed   
--http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81432/how-do-i-use-powershell-to-get-a-sql-server-backup-status

--marcelo miorelli
--19-nov-2014
--=====================================================================================================================

   DECLARE @Body VARCHAR(MAX),
        @TableHead VARCHAR(MAX),
        @TableTail VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET NoCount ON ;


    SET @TableTail = '</body></html>' ;

    SET @TableHead = '<html><head>' + '<style>'
        + 'td {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:10pt;} '
        + '</style>' + '</head>' + '<body>'


    SELECT  @Body = ''



    SELECT  @Body = @Body + '<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>'
            + '<tr><td bgcolor=#E6E6FA>Database Name </td>'
            + '<td width="100px" bgcolor=#E6E6FA>Backup Size</td>'
            + '<td width="100px" bgcolor=#E6E6FA>Time Taken</td>'
            + '<td width="100px" bgcolor=#E6E6FA>Backup Start Date</td>'
            + '<td width="100px" bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>First LSN</b></td>'
            + '<td width="100px" bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Last LSN</b></td>'
            + '<td width="100px" bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Backup Type</b></td>'
            + '<td width="100px" bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Server Name</b></td>'
            + '<td width="100px" bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Recovery Model</b></td>'
            + '<td width="300px" bgcolor=#E6E6FA>Physical Device Name</td>   </tr>'


    -- Backup History script of AAsim Adbullah                
    -- http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/11/10/sql-server-get-database-backup-history-for-a-single-database/ 
    SELECT  @Body = @Body
            + ( SELECT  td = s.database_name, '',
                        td = CAST(CAST(s.backup_size / 1000000 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(14))+ ' ' + 'MB', '',
                        td = CAST(DATEDIFF(second, s.backup_start_date,
                                           s.backup_finish_date) AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' ' + 'Seconds', '',
                        td = s.backup_start_date,  '',
                        td = CAST(s.first_lsn AS VARCHAR(50)), '',
                        td = CAST(s.last_lsn AS VARCHAR(50)), '',
                        td = CASE s.[type]
                               WHEN 'D' THEN 'Full'
                               WHEN 'I' THEN 'Differential'
                               WHEN 'L' THEN 'Transaction Log'
                             END,'',
                        td = s.server_name, '',
                        td = s.recovery_model,'',
                        td = m.physical_device_name,''
                FROM    msdb.dbo.backupset s
                        INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily m ON s.media_set_id = m.media_set_id
                WHERE   1=1
                  AND   s.backup_start_date >= DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,GETDATE() - 1)) -- --- Date check for one day backup history information
                  AND   s.[type] IN ('D','I') -- ignoring the transaction log backups
                ORDER BY backup_start_date DESC,
                        backup_finish_date
              FOR
                XML PATH('tr')
              ) + '</table>'



    SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body, '_x0020_', SPACE(1))
    SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body, '_x003D_', '=')
    SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body, '<tr><TRRow>1</TRRow>', '<tr bgcolor=#C6CFFF>')
    SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body, '<TRRow>0</TRRow>', '')


    SELECT  @Body = @TableHead + @Body + @TableTail

    --select @Body

    IF ( @Body IS NULL ) 
        BEGIN 
                EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='mmiorelli@mycompany.co.uk',  -- Add Valid Email Id
                @subject = 'Backup History Information',
                @profile_name = 'DBA', -- Change Profile Name
                @body = 'No Backup History Found for past 1 Day',
                @body_format = 'HTML' ;

        END
    ELSE 
    Begin
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='mmiorelli@amycompany.co.uk', -- Add Valid Email Id
                @subject = 'Backup History Information',
                @profile_name = 'DBA', -- Change Profile Name
                @body = @Body,
                @body_format = 'HTML' ;
    END
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually super easy, and you don't even need to go through the trouble of doing `INSERT... EXEC` with the stored proc.

```
USE msdb

EXEC sp_helptext 'sysmail_help_account_sp'
```

This will return the script info:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sysmail_help_account_sp  
   @account_id int = NULL,  
   @account_name sysname = NULL  
AS  
   SET NOCOUNT ON  

   DECLARE @rc int  
   DECLARE @accountid int  
   exec @rc = msdb.dbo.sysmail_verify_account_sp @account_id, @account_name, 1, 0, @accountid OUTPUT  
   IF @rc <> 0  
      RETURN(1)  

   IF (@accountid IS NOT NULL)  
      SELECT a.account_id, a.name, a.description, a.email_address, a.display_name, a.replyto_address, s.servertype, s.servername, s.port, s.username, s.use_default_credentials, s.enable_ssl   
      FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_account a, msdb.dbo.sysmail_server s  
      WHERE a.account_id = s.account_id AND a.account_id = @accountid  

   ELSE  
      SELECT a.account_id, a.name, a.description, a.email_address, a.display_name, a.replyto_address, s.servertype, s.servername, s.port, s.username, s.use_default_credentials, s.enable_ssl  
      FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_account a, msdb.dbo.sysmail_server s  
      WHERE a.account_id = s.account_id  

   RETURN(0)
```

You can see that it just queries these system views in msdb:

```
SELECT *
FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_account a, msdb.dbo.sysmail_server s  
WHERE a.account_id = s.account_id
```

Which should be easy to integrate into your process.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

[@Erik Darling](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/177613/10832) has a great method of extracting the account name from the msdb table directly.  Use that method.

However, to help you understand how you could use the `INSERT INTO ... EXEC` construct, I've written this little snippet of code:

```
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @params nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @ProfileName sysname;
DECLARE @ColumnList nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @tsql nvarchar(max);

SET @params = '@ProfileName sysname OUTPUT';

SET @tsql = N'EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_account_sp;'

SET @Command = N'CREATE TABLE #sysmailaccount
(
    <COLUMNLIST>
);';

SET @ColumnList = '';
SET @ColumnList = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(rs.name) + ' ' + rs.system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@tsql, NULL, NULL) rs
ORDER BY rs.column_ordinal
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '');

SET @Command = REPLACE(@Command, N'<COLUMNLIST>', @ColumnList);

SET @Command = @Command + N'
INSERT INTO #sysmailaccount
' + @tsql + N';
SELECT @ProfileName = sma.name
FROM #sysmailaccount sma;
';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Command, @params, @ProfileName = @ProfileName OUT;
SELECT ProfileName = @ProfileName;
```

At the end of above code, you have `@ProfileName` containing the name of the first database mail profile name.

The code uses the `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` system function to construct a temporary table with the same definition as the output of `msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_account_sp`.  It then uses `sys.sp_executesql` to execute an `INSERT INTO ... EXEC` command to actually run the `sysmail_help_account_sp` stored proc, placing the output into the `#sysmailaccount` temp table.