# How to connect to microsoft azure?

Tags: sql-server, backup, availability-groups, sql-server-2016, azure-blob-storage

We have been saving the backups of one of our production servers ([which is actually an Always On availability group](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2880/backing-up-sql-server-databases-participating-in-alwayson-availability-groups/))

[this is how I am doing my backups and saving to azure](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html):

```
    sqlcmd -E -S $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR)) -d master 
-Q "EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup 
@AvailabilityGroups = 'SQLAG',
@URL = 'https://MYCOMPANYbackups.blob.core.windows.net/SQLMAINSERVER-datafiles-full',
@Credential = 'SQLAzureCredential',
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Compress = 'Y',
@Verify = 'Y',
@LogToTable = 'Y'" -b
```

This is what I see when attempting to connect to Azure:
what would be my storage account?
[image]

I have a job that I have scheduled to send me an email about all the backups on a server. The [script that collect information about the backups and send the email is here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177610/the-database-mail-configuration-saved-into-a-temp-table).

The email tells me where the backup is.
for example:

here is a picture for illustration purposes:
[image]

How can I have access to the backup files?

Where are these [azure permissions managed](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=where%20are%20azure%20permissions%20managed&oq=where%20are%20azure%20permissions%20managed&aqs=chrome..69i57.10407j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

**EDIT:**

The answer by [David Browne](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/126936/david-browne-microsoft) got me there, thank you David.

I am just adding here a set of steps that took me to my backups (after successfully connecting to azure).

01 - Click on `Blob`

[image]

02 - select one of the containers

[image]

03 - the files will be there - ready for dowloading

[image]

This article is also very interesting:

[First look: back up files and folders in Resource Manager deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-try-azure-backup-in-10-mins)

Comment: Do you have access to your azure portal? Username and pw? Looking at your backup code it appers `MYCOMPANYbackups` is your storage account name. You will need to grab the key or ask someone who has access.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> what would be my storage account?

MYCOMPANYbackups

> How can I have access to the backup files?

http://portal.azure.com
or
[AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy)
or
[PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-powershell-guide-full)
or
[Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/)

> Where are these azure permissions managed?

Permissions for accessing the blobs is controlled by the storage account keys, or Shared Access Signatures.  See [Azure Storage Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-security-guide)

Comment: awesome explanation with respective link. For +1