# Is there a way to set an order to the way files are available in Azure? I want the latest backup first

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2016, azure, azure-blob-storage

[I use Azure to store backups](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/178180/how-to-connect-to-microsoft-azure), the backups are saved in Azure.

[this is how I am doing my backups and saving to azure](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html):

```
    sqlcmd -E -S $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR)) -d master 
-Q "EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup 
@AvailabilityGroups = 'SQLAG',
@URL = 'https://MYCOMPANYbackups.blob.core.windows.net/SQLMAINSERVER-datafiles-full',
@Credential = 'SQLAzureCredential',
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Compress = 'Y',
@Verify = 'Y',
@LogToTable = 'Y'" -b
```

This is working fine.

There are some points I would like\need to improve though. When I need to restore a backup from Azure the backups are stored in the order they have been saved, and generally I need the most recent backup.

For example the picture below (apologies I have used this thick green to hide sensitive information like server, accounts and database names, it got really ugly but just to have an idea):

these are `differential`  backups:
[image]

As I often need the latest backup of an specific database(s) is there a way to order how the files are stored in azure so that the first one available is the latest saved?

**conclusion**

After downloading and installing `Microsoft Azure Storage Exporer`
I can order the backup files as you can see on the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change how the files are stored in Azure but I guess you don't want to, you just want so change the sort order of the view in the Azure portal?

In that case I recommend using Microsoft [Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) instead.